# How do I get bash to read this docker command parameter correctly?

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to run the following command in a bash script:

`docker build --tag mytag --label description="my description blah" .`

The problem is that I can't figure out how to parameterize the entire label argument.

The above works but this throws `ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.`:

```
derp='--label description="my description with spaces"'
echo $derp # show the full parameter correctly
docker build --tag mytag $derp .
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). You can't use literal quotes to substitute for syntactic quotes; `echo` shows you literal values, it _doesn't_ show you syntactic quoting, and what you need is syntax.

Comment: `derp=( --label description="my description with spaces" )`, then `docker build --tag mytag "${derp[@]}"` does the right thing, _even though `echo` doesn't show it_. That's because `echo` is a bad tool for the job; use `declare -p derp` to see what's in `derp`.

Comment: (which languages are you most fluent in? I was about to try to make the data-vs-syntax distinction clear through analogy, but it's not obvious from your profile which language I should make an analogy _to_)

Comment: ...eh, Let's say Python. If you run `derp=[ '--label', '--description=my description with spaces' ]` and then run `subprocess.run(['docker', 'build', '--tag', 'mytag'] + derp)`, the quotes in that are all _Python_ syntax, not shell syntax, and the quotes themselves are never passed to `docker` itself. Same for C, if you run `**char{"docker", "build", "--tag", "mytag", "--label", "--description=my description blah", NULL}`, the double quotes there are C syntax, not data. And it's still true in shell: quotes in your shell commands when not escaped or in other quotes are _shell syntax, not data_.

Comment: (note too that when parsed as shell syntax, `--description="my description with spaces"` and `"--description=my description with spaces"` are _the exact same string_, 100% identical to `--description=my\ description\ with\ spaces`; the quotes or backslashes aren't part of the data passed to docker, but are only part of the syntax the shell uses to determine whether spaces are literal data or separators used at parse time)

Comment: The issue you're encountering is related to how the shell interprets the variable with multiple parameters as a single argument.
This will work



```
#!/bin/bash

derp=(--label description="my description with spaces")

echo "${derp[@]}" # show the full parameter correctly
docker build --tag mytag "${derp[@]}" .
```

Comment: @MichealChoudhary, it's a stretch to say `echo "${derp[@]}"` will show the value correctly -- one won't know if quoting is correct from its output. `echo "${derp[@]}"` has exactly the same output from `derp=( "--description=my" "description with" "spaces" )` and `derp=( "--description=my description with spaces" )`, even though only one of those two is correct. Now, what _would_ be correct if we could guarantee bash 5.0 or later is `printf '%s\n' "${derp[*]@Q}"` (using `printf` to avoid echo's [ambiguities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819)).